# Available languages for speech recognition

Tags: android

From what I've read, speech recognition is available for 3 languages: English (UK, US, Au ..), Japanese and Chinese (Mandarin).

Does anyone know more details about how to switch between these languages?
Is there a way to know (programatically) which language is active for speech recognition on a certain device? (maybe in Japan the only have Japanese ... but can I get this information somehow ... like a property or anything?).

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Please try to make your titles more descriptive. For example: "Available languages for speech recognition"

Answer (score 3):

To switch between languages, just use the Locale you want for the language and set `Locale.toString` for `EXTRA_LANGAUGE` in you `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` intent.

To check what languages are available, you need something like this:

```
    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(
            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
    LanguageDetailsChecker checker = new LanguageDetailsChecker();
    sendOrderedBroadcast(detailsIntent, null, checker, null,
            Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

Where LanguageDetailsChecker is a BroadcastReceiver defined as something like this:

```
public class LanguageDetailsChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "LanguageDetailsChecker";

    private List<String> supportedLanguages;

    private String languagePreference;

    public LanguageDetailsChecker() {
        supportedLanguages = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
        if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE)) {
            languagePreference = results
                    .getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE);
        }
        if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) {
            supportedLanguages = results
                    .getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);
        }
    }
}
```

All this code is part of [this project](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/LanguageDetailsChecker.java).

Comment: Great! this is useful. Only one thing we found incomplete.
When running  on Android 8.x, Bundle results got nothing inside "Bundle[{}]"! Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: But the problem is when you want to use it, it does not work perfectly, for e.g. with Chinese language because you simply cannot create `Locale` to start recognition

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at android.speech.RecognizerIntent It looks like you can get Language support info from there by calling getVoiceDetailsIntent().

Have a look at the API docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#getVoiceDetailsIntent%28android.content.Context%29)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, always returning null bundle. I found similar issues raised across internet. Can anyone tell if it works, and how to use it properly?