# How to teach Android Speech recognizer a new language

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to build a speech recognizer to android for a native language (Non-English language, Mongolian). Is there any tool I can use to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android STT has no tools to add a new languages, other external libraries have them. For example, you can add Mongolian language to [Pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid)

The tutorial for adding a new language is provided [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Android Speech recognition Api for this purpose and it's quite easy to use.
You can pass language code in the intent like this :

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
```

and Here you go!
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257598/what-are-language-codes-for-voice-recognition-languages-in-chromes-implementati) is the list of language codes.
And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538791/how-to-set-the-language-in-speech-recognition-on-android/10548680#10548680) is the way how you do it.
If you want a complete tutorial then follow [this](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-android-voice-recognition/) or [this detailed](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-build-a-speak-and-repeat-app--mobile-11197) tutorial.
Cheers!!

Comment: Is there any way to do this for non-supported languages like Mongolian?

Comment: @Suragch you can check if Mongolian is supported or not though this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/7893333/3651574

Comment: Yup, Thanx it is certainly the answer for languages which support this method.
Well I want to identify names too. Lets say a name of a town or a person Which obviously not in the vocabulary of the recognizer. So is there a way to achieve that?
And if the native language is not supported for this method. In this case what methods can I use to achieve a recognizer?

Comment: @Fahid Nadeem, I'm pretty sure Mongolian is not supported. But even if it is, how do you get speech recognition for an unsupported language?