# How to prompt Languages List of Google Voice Input Settings screen programmatically

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice

I write an app using Google SpeechRecognizer and I know how to set the language for SpeechRecognizer.

Now I want to make use of the default language setting/select of Google Voice Input. How to programmatically prompt the language-select of Google Voice Input?

Google Voice input language setting:

[image: Google Voice input language setting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cost a lot time to search and find nothing to prompt Languages List of Google Voice Input Settings screen programmatically.
  But find other guys' another solution to accomplish similar thing I want. This may be better for it can let an app independently set recognition language.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7893333/8046317